# Batch Size in kafka jdbc sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, connector

I want to read only 5000 records in a batch through jdbc sink, for which I've used the batch.size in the jdbc sink config file:

```
name=jdbc-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
batch.size=5000
topics=postgres_users

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:34771/postgres?user=foo&password=bar
file=test.sink.txt
auto.create=true
```

But the batch.size has no effect as records are getting inserted into the database when new records are inserted into the source database.

How can I achieve to insert in a batch of 5000?

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct solution to sink records in batches but we give try tune below property if it works. I have never tried but my understanding Kafka Sink Connector nothing but a consumer to consume message from the topic.

**max.poll.records:** The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll()

**consumer.fetch.min.bytes:** The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request

**fetch.wait.max.ms:** The broker will wait for this amount of time BEFORE sending a response to the consumer client unless it has enough data to fill the response (fetch.message.max.bytes)

**fetch.min.bytes:** The broker will wait for this amount of data to fill BEFORE it sends the response to the consumer client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was helpful but I am using JDBC sink connector and I don't think we have these configs at connector level and I don't want these configurations to affect other connectors so I cant put these globally

Answer (score 3):

In order to set the batch size you have two options:

- Add **max.poll.records=5000** in your worker.properties file used by the Kafka Connect instance (standalone or distributed);
- Set the same property in the connector configuration file (the JSON file for distributed connectors).

For the second option, you have to:

- Enable the possibility to override connect properties by adding **connector.client.config.override.policy=All** in the worker.properties
- Configure the batch size with **"consumer.override.max.poll.records" : 2000**  in the connector configuration (notice the "*consumer.override.*" prefix)